# How do I swap fragments, still within the same MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a *MainActivity* that contains a *main fragment* and a *bottom navigation bar* (bottom navigation bar decides which fragment to display).

**=====SCENARIO====**

Lets say in my bottom navigation bar, I have buttons A, B and C, which toggles to A,B and C states.
When I clock on button B, I want it to go to a particular fragment. I Got this already.

---

**I am unable to achieve this currently:**

However within the fragment I have a button, that upon clicking, should bring me to another fragment, BUT on the bottom navigation bar, im still within state B.
Eg: clicking the button will show me another page to fill up some form

---

I am not sure what is the best approach to this. Any expertise is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: > "BUT on the bottom navigation bar, im still within state B"...

@Daryll, is preserving state B on nav bar desired behavior or something you need to avoid?
In case it's not desired, what should happen with nav bar when the form is shown?

Comment: Hmmm state B may or may not be desired. 
I think currently there are 2 ways to do this, 

1) If it is not desired, then clicking the button would create an intent to another activity (that does not have the bottom nav bar), and once the form is done, it will jump back to my MainActivity with bottom nav bar
---is this approach bad? 
2) If it is desired, this i do not know how to achieve haha.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, which is to 
**Perform Fragment Transactions**

Check this [android resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

For transiting between activities, you create and start an intent, however for fragments, you perform fragment transactions.

The code below should be easy to understand:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Side note here is the `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`
This preserves the backstate of this transaction. Ie, when you click the back button, it knows where to go to - the previous fragment (which may be a little dumbfounding as both fragments are still within the same state of the mainactivity (usually one of the button tabs).